# Displaying array values through object that references other methods not displaying with for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, polymorphism, parameter-passing

Basically, the point of my program is a payroll program for the user to input amount of employees, then with that same amount of employees go through the process of indicating what kind of employee it is, and then proceed to enter information of employee based on type. Right now, I am going one at a time and first starting out with hourly. I managed to get the output I wanted until I end up completing the while loop's condition to go on and output the resulting table but it does not output the results and only outputs the column labels. I decided to use a for loop so that it continues to display until it reaches a number greater than the size. I checked to see if I was using correct formatting for the array[e].method(); but cant seem to catch anything wrong so far.

Could it be a possibility of the parameters not matching or probably a misuse of it?

Thanks in advance.

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Welcome to the Company's Payroll System!");
  System.out.println("Please enter the amount of employees in the company.");
  int size = in.nextInt();
  Employee [] staff = new Employee [size];

  int i = 0;

  while (i != staff.length ) 
      {

      System.out.println("Enter employee type (Choose Hourly, Salary, or Manager)");
      System.out.println("Press 4 to exit.");
      String emptype = in.next();

     if (emptype.equalsIgnoreCase("Hourly")) 
     {
        System.out.println("First name:"); 
        String first = in.next();

        System.out.println("Last name:");
        String last = in.next();

        System.out.println("Employee ID (7 digits):");
        Float identification = in.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Job Title:");
        String title = in.next();

        System.out.println("Amount employee makes per hour: ");
        double hour = in.nextDouble();

        staff [i] = new HourlyEmployee(first, last, identification, title, hour);

        i++;
     }

      }


       System.out.println("FIRST NAME \t LAST NAME \t ID \t JOB TITLE \t Weekly Salary");
       for (int e = 0; e > size; e++)
       {
       System.out.printf("%5d", staff[e].getfirstName() + staff[e].getlastName() + staff[e].getId() + staff[e].getTitle() + staff[e].weeklyPay() );}
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop your condition is wrong. It should be:

```
for (int e=0; e < size; e++)
```